# Creating an Amazon S3 bucket Using the AWS SDK for Java : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, api, amazon-s3

Getting below error while trying to create an s3 bucket of aws using java API :

Error : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: software/amazon/awssdk/protocols/query/internal/unmarshall/AwsXmlErrorUnmarshaller at software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.xml.internal.unmarshall.AwsXmlErrorTransformer.(AwsXmlErrorTransformer.java:40) at software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.xml.internal.unmarshall.AwsXmlErrorTransformer.(AwsXmlErrorTransformer.java:34) at software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.xml.internal.unmarshall.AwsXmlErrorTransformer$Builder.build(AwsXmlErrorTransformer.java:113) at software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.xml.AwsXmlProtocolFactory.createErrorTransformer(AwsXmlProtocolFactory.java:135) at software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.xml.AwsS3ProtocolFactory.createErrorCouldBeInBodyResponseHandler(AwsS3ProtocolFactory.java:80) at software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.DefaultS3Client.createBucket(DefaultS3Client.java:1144) at com.act.niti.main(niti.java:33) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.query.internal.unmarshall.AwsXmlErrorUnmarshaller at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418) at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351) ..

Code :

```
 try {
     Region region = Region.US_EAST_2; 
     S3Client s3 = S3Client.builder()
        .region(region)
        .build();
         S3Waiter s3Waiter = s3.waiter();
         CreateBucketRequest bucketRequest = CreateBucketRequest.builder()
                .bucket("abc")
                .build();
         
        
         s3.createBucket(bucketRequest); //creating s3 bucket
          System.out.println("bucket........abc");
          HeadBucketRequest bucketRequestWait = HeadBucketRequest.builder()
          .bucket("abc")
          .build();
          
          // Wait until the bucket is created and print out the response
          WaiterResponse<HeadBucketResponse> waiterResponse =
          s3Waiter.waitUntilBucketExists(bucketRequestWait);
          waiterResponse.matched().response().ifPresent(System.out::println);
          System.out.println("abc" +" is ready");
         

    } catch (S3Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
        System.exit(1);
    }
            Note : Using java 8
```

POM Xml :

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.570</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>s3</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.269</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>ec2</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.10</version>
        </dependency>       
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-gamelift -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-gamelift</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.647</version>
        </dependency>
        

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-commons</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>s3-transfer-manager</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.103-PREVIEW</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependencies>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are mixing up V1 and V2 in your POM file. You have

```
  <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.570</version>
  </dependency>
```

There is no need for this Dep when using AWS SDK for V2. **S3Client** is a V2 Service Client. In fact -- your errors are most likely related to mxing up SDK versions in your POM file.

The POM file that you should use can be found in the AWS Github repo here:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2/example_code/s3

If you are not familiar with **AWS SDK for Java v2**, refer to the DEV Guide:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/home.html

The V2 Java code that works when you use the proper POM file is here:

```
package com.example.s3;

// snippet-start:[s3.java2.create_bucket_waiters.import]
import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.ProfileCredentialsProvider;
import software.amazon.awssdk.core.waiters.WaiterResponse;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.S3Client;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.CreateBucketRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.HeadBucketRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.HeadBucketResponse;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Exception;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.waiters.S3Waiter;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
// snippet-end:[s3.java2.create_bucket_waiters.import]

/**
 * Before running this Java V2 code example, set up your development environment, including your credentials.
 *
 * For more information, see the following documentation topic:
 *
 * https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html
 */

public class CreateBucket {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException {

        final String usage = "\n" +
            "Usage:\n" +
            "    <bucketName> \n\n" +
            "Where:\n" +
            "    bucketName - The name of the bucket to create. The bucket name must be unique, or an error occurs.\n\n" ;

       if (args.length != 1) {
           System.out.println(usage);
           System.exit(1);
       }

        String bucketName = args[0];
        System.out.format("Creating a bucket named %s\n", bucketName);
        ProfileCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = ProfileCredentialsProvider.create();
        Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
        S3Client s3 = S3Client.builder()
            .region(region)
            .credentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
            .build();

        createBucket (s3, bucketName);
        s3.close();
    }

    // snippet-start:[s3.java2.create_bucket_waiters.main]
    public static void createBucket( S3Client s3Client, String bucketName) {

        try {
            S3Waiter s3Waiter = s3Client.waiter();
            CreateBucketRequest bucketRequest = CreateBucketRequest.builder()
                .bucket(bucketName)
                .build();

            s3Client.createBucket(bucketRequest);
            HeadBucketRequest bucketRequestWait = HeadBucketRequest.builder()
                .bucket(bucketName)
                .build();

            // Wait until the bucket is created and print out the response.
            WaiterResponse<HeadBucketResponse> waiterResponse = s3Waiter.waitUntilBucketExists(bucketRequestWait);
            waiterResponse.matched().response().ifPresent(System.out::println);
            System.out.println(bucketName +" is ready");

        } catch (S3Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
    // snippet-end:[s3.java2.create_bucket_waiters.main]
}
```

Comment: using the latest java sdk now  and also used all the dependencies as per mentioned in the above link still getting the same error : 
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>1.12.299</version>

Comment: From your comment -- you still have <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId> <version>1.12.299</version>

Comment: Shoukd be no mention of 1.12.299